# Data is not picked up from instantiated outputs

Tags: hardware, verilog, fpga, hdl

I have instantiated a stopwatch module into this multiplexer module. The stopwatch is working as it is supposed to and is producing the expected output. This is also picked up by the instantiated registers. But, if I want to use this data further down the module, it does not work.

Here is the simulation showing my problem:

[image]

The values picked up from the stopwatch module are working perfectly. These values are then transferred to the registers `regd0, regd1, regd2, regd3` which, instead of displaying the values are displaying `0`?

Here is the code that produced the above simulation:

```
    module muxer(
    input clock,
    input reset,
    input [1:0] select,
    output a,
    output b,
    output c,
    output d,
    output e,
    output f,
    output g,
    output dp,
    output [3:0] an
    );

reg go_hi, go_start;

wire[3:0] wire_d0, wire_d1, wire_d2, wire_d3; // timer registers that will hold the individual counts
wire[3:0] wire_hd0, wire_hd1, wire_hd2, wire_hd3; //regsiters to hold the "hi" values
reg [3:0] regd0, regd1, regd2, regd3; //registers for LED multiplexing

//instantiate the "hi" module
say_hi sayhi(.clock(clock), .reset(reset), .go(go_hi), .hi_d0(wire_hd0), .hi_d1(wire_hd1), .hi_d2(wire_hd2), .hi_d3(wire_hd3)) ;

//instantiate the stopwatch module
stopwatch timer(.clock(clock), .reset(reset), .start(go_start), .d0(wire_d0), .d1(wire_d1), .d2(wire_d2), .d3(wire_d3) );

always @ (select)
begin
    case(select)
        00: //hi
        begin
            go_start = 0; //make sure timer module is off
            go_hi = 1'b1; //enable go signal to display "hi"
            regd0 = wire_hd0; //transfer values to the multiplexing circuit
            regd1 = wire_hd1;
            regd2 = wire_hd2;
            regd3 = wire_hd3;
        end
        
        01: //timer
        begin
            go_hi = 0; //make sure "hi" module is off
            go_start = 1'b1; //enable start signal to start timer
            regd0 = wire_d0;
            regd1 = wire_d1;
            regd2 = wire_d2;
            regd3 = wire_d3;
        end
        
        10: //stop timer
        begin
            go_hi = 0;
            go_start = 1'b0;
        end
    endcase
end

//The Circuit for 7 Segment Multiplexing - 

localparam N = 8; //18 for implementation, 8 for simulation

reg [N-1:0]count;

always @ (posedge clock or posedge reset)
    begin
        if (reset)
            count <= 0;
        else
            count <= count + 1;
    end

reg [6:0]sseg;
reg [3:0]an_temp;
reg reg_dp;
always @ (*)
    begin
        case(count[N-1:N-2])
            
            2'b00 : 
                begin
                    sseg = regd0;
                    an_temp = 4'b1110;
                    reg_dp = 1'b1;
                end
            
            2'b01:
                begin
                    sseg = regd1;
                    an_temp = 4'b1101;
                    reg_dp = 1'b0;
                end
            
            2'b10:
                begin
                    sseg = regd2;
                    an_temp = 4'b1011;
                    reg_dp = 1'b1;
                end
                
            2'b11:
                begin
                    sseg = regd3;
                    an_temp = 4'b0111;
                    reg_dp = 1'b0;
                end
        endcase
    end
assign an = an_temp;

reg [6:0] sseg_temp;    
always @ (*)
    begin
        case(sseg)
            4'd0 : sseg_temp = 7'b1000000; //display 0
            4'd1 : sseg_temp = 7'b1111001; //display 1
            4'd2 : sseg_temp = 7'b0100100;// display 2
            4'd3 : sseg_temp = 7'b0110000;
            4'd4 : sseg_temp = 7'b0011001;
            4'd5 : sseg_temp = 7'b0010010;
            4'd6 : sseg_temp = 7'b0000010;
            4'd7 : sseg_temp = 7'b1111000;
            4'd8 : sseg_temp = 7'b0000000;
            4'd9 : sseg_temp = 7'b0010000;
            4'd10 : sseg_temp = 7'b0001001; //to display H
            4'd11 : sseg_temp = 7'b0000111; //to display I
            default : sseg_temp = 7'b0111111; //dash
        endcase
    end
assign {g, f, e, d, c, b, a} = sseg_temp;   
assign dp = reg_dp;

endmodule
```

Comment: Careful about latching regd* when select is b'10 or b'11. As a general rule, for every signal that you're muxing in a `select`, you should drive it in every case (or assign a default, preferably `x` before the case statement so that a latch is not inferred).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `select` does not equal 01.  You should show that in waves as well.

Here are a couple of other observations.

If you want `regd0` to model combinational logic, you should change `always @(select)` to `always @*`.  Same for d1-d3.  Currently, I think you are modeling latches.

In your case statement `10` refers to decimal 10.  You probably wanted `2'b10`.